# How to use two middleware with register method node-restful?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, restful-authentication

Is it possible to use two middleware with the 'register' method (node-restful)?

Router.js:

```
personService.register(protectedApi, '/person');
```

PersonService.js:

```
Person.methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']);

Person.updateOptions({new: true, runValidators: true});

Person.after('post', sendErrorsOrNext).after('put', sendErrorsOrNext);
```

I need get one information of middleware 1 and pass to o middleware 2, but I would like use register method of node-restful.

Is it possible?